# Disable button while processing request

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to wpf and xaml (Windows development in general) and my background is asp.net and prior to that classic ASP.

I'm working on an application that needs to have the button disabled/grayed out while the processing occurs and read a post on here to do the following but it doesn't appear to be working. What am I missing?

```
<Window x:Class="SCGen.Application.LoadForecast.EngineExecution"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"        
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    Title="Engine Execution"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="myStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ExecuteEngine}" />
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Execute Engine" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Command" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>    
<Border Padding="8">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Select Forecast Engine" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" />

            <igEditors:XamComboEditor ItemsSource="{Binding ForecastEngines}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEngine}" Margin="0,5" />

            <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EngineStatus}" FontSize="15" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="0,14" Width="400" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>

</Window>
```

I've changed the xaml to the following:

```
<Button Content="Execute Weather Import" Command="{Binding ExecuteWeather}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

In the ViewModel I have the following:

```
private bool _isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    { 
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { _isEnabled = value; }
    }
```

and I set the _isEnabled here:

```
private string LaunchWeatherImport(string strVendor)
    {
        _isEnabled = false;

        string uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManualExecutionFacilitatorService"];
        ClientConnectionInfo connection = new ClientConnectionInfo(uri) { UseSecurity = true };
        connection.SetTimeouts();

        Logger.LogInfo("Calling Facilitator service to manually import " + strVendor + " weather data.");

        ((NetTcpBinding)connection.Binding).Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.None;

        using (var client = new FacilitatorManualExecutionClient(connection))
        {
            client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OperationTimeOutMinutes"]));

            try
            {
                _isEnabled = true;
                return "success";
                // uncomment this line before commit
                //return client.ExecuteWeather(strVendor);
            }
            #region catch
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                return ex.Message;
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

I still can't get it to work properly.

Comment: I guess question is already answered, but I\`d like to point out that when using commands you can just use `CanExecute` method for disabling controls associated with particular command. If interested, you can read some info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.canexecute.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you're setting the trigger on the Command property but you don't have a binding set on that property for your button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myStyle}" />
```

Should be:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myStyle}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

[Where MyCommand is the name of your actual command that you're binding to]

I am not so sure that it will work anyway though because your trigger is set to fire when the Command property is null, but if you bind to the command property, following the MVVM pattern then your command property shouldn't be null so the trigger won't fire then either.

UPDATE:

You need to implemented the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface on your class that has the property.

```
public class MyClass : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then add the implementation:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Then change your property to be:

```
private bool _isEnabled = true;
public bool IsEnabled
{ 
    get { return _isEnabled; }
    set 
    { 
       _isEnabled = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply.  I changed the button tag to the way you mentioned above and still no dice.  This app does follow MVVM and I've not worked with MVVM, WPF, or Xaml prior to this.  What should the trigger use rather than x:Null to make it work properly?

Comment: I am assuming that you got the code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138026/how-to-disable-button-when-its-button-commandproperty-is-null ?
If that is the case then you should note that their example works because their Command interface is using the CanExecute function. So when the command can execute, the command is returned to the binding, otherwise it's null. That is why it works in their example.  Another way you can accomplish this is by creating a backing IsButtonEnabled property in the ViewModel and binding your button's IsEnabled property to this property.

Comment: Yes I did, either that post or another one that's similar.  I actually created a property in the viewmodel:  

private bool _isEnabled = true;
        public bool IsEnabled
        { 
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set { _isEnabled = value; }
        }

In the xaml:  
<Button Content="Execute Weather Import" Command="{Binding ExecuteWeather}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>

I'm setting the property to false when the code executes and back to true after execution but still no dice.

Comment: You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your class which has the property and then call the notify function in your property after the set. This will let your UI know that the property has changed and so the UI needs to be redrawn needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I've done as you suggested and it should be working now.  This ViewModel inherits from a base class that has the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented inside of it.  I added the call to RaisePropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled"); in my property setter.  I appreciate your help.  It doesn't look like the button is being disabled but I think that's because the code is executing too fast and the values are switched in milliseconds.